# iOS - Navigation Bar transparent transition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to make a Navigation Bar that goes transparent in detail but with my current code the Bar doesn't return to it's non transparent state. How can this be fixed? I want to this code to also work in the MoreNavigationController from the UITabBarController.

**The code that has been placed in the Detail ViewController.**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { [weak self](context) in
        self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        }, completion: { context in
    })
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { [weak self](context) in
        self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
        }, completion: { context in
    })
}
```

[image: Example of the Navigation Bar]

Comment: What you're doing is just wrong. Don't try to change the nav bar's transparency like that between view controllers. The nav bar belongs to the navigation controller, not the view controllers; once configured, it should just stay the same way forever. Also, I can see you have a mismatch of your view controller extended edges; they need to be the same (i.e. all view controllers should underlap the nav bar or none of them).

Comment: Instead of pushing a view controller, you can always present one with a custom animation.

Comment: @Brandon What do you mean? Moving the code above into a custom transition gives the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Add the code below to `DetailViewController`. 
It was confirmed that this code also works in the `UINavigationController` from the `UITabBarController`.

***NextController.swift***

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setNavigationBar()
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) { 
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    }
    

    func setNavigationBar() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    }
}
```

### Preview

[image]

[image]